# How to transfer a pandas data frame to a customized one and data clean it despite the order of pandas-set headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, data-cleaning

So I try to import a number of excels and data clean them and here is my code for it:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import math
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)

header = list(df.columns.values)
print(header) 

df = df.where(df.notnull(), None)
array = df.values.tolist()
#print(array)
class Item():
    __name = ""
    __cost = 0
    __gender = ""
    __prime = ""

    def has_all_properties(self):
        return bool(self.__name and not math.isnan(self.__cost) and self.__gender and self.__prime)

    def clean(self,wanted_cost,wanted_gender,wanted_prime):
        return bool(self.__name and self.__cost <= wanted_cost and self.__gender == wanted_gender and self.__prime == wanted_prime)
    
    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self.__name = name
        self.__cost = cost
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__prime = prime

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.__name == other.__name and self.__cost == other.__cost and self.__gender == other.__gender and self.__prime == other.__prime)   
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.__name, self.__cost, self.__gender, self.__prime))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.__name},{self.__cost},{self.__gender},{self.__prime})"

    def tuple(self): 
        return self.__name, self.__cost, self.__gender, self.__prime

mylist = {Item(*k) for k in array}
print(mylist)

filtered = {obj for obj in mylist if obj.has_all_properties()}
clean = {obj for obj in filtered if obj.clean(20,"male","yes")}
result = list(clean)
print(result)


t_list = [obj.tuple() for obj in result]
output = pd.DataFrame(t_list, columns = header)
output.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```

the excel I import from look something like this:

```
    product cost   used_by prime
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    ... and so on
```

However, not all of them have the odder of `product cost  used_by prime`(case one order). Some of them, for example, are in the format of `cost product used_by prime`(case two order). Of course, pandas would be able to auto-sort them and make sure the data find the right header, but I run into an issue.

So basically, I run this code on two different devices using the same data and code but the result lists are different. One of them is in case one order while the other one is in the case two order.

case one order look something like this:

```
array= [['comic', 20.0, 'male', 'yes'], 
        ['paint', 14.0, 'male', 'no'], 
        ['pen', 5.0, 'female', 'yes'], 
        ['phone case', 9.0, 'female', 'no'], 
        ['headphone', 40.0, 'male', 'yes'], 
        [None, 17.0, 'male', 'yes'], 
        ... and so on]
```

case two is like this:

```
array = [[20.0, 'comic', 'male', 'yes'], 
         [14.0, 'paint', 'male', 'no'], 
         [5.0,'pen', 'female', 'yes'], 
         [9.0, 'phone case', 'female', 'no'], 
         [40.0, 'headphone', 'male', 'yes'], 
         [17.0, None, 'male', 'yes'],  
         ... and so on]
```

So, this caused a problem, when I try to data clean them, the code I have can only work with case one and not all the other options. So, I am thinking of using the header to tell my class function how to arrange the data. For example, if pandas arange the data frame as case one, the class function will use the header of case one and follow that to data clean and get a output like case one, and if the arrangement is in case two, it will change to case two and still able to data clean.  But, I am not sure how to do that.

Coming to think of it, it is not really a matter of devices since if I change the order of my data on the same device, the result pandas data frame will end up being different. The issue is finding a way of able to data clean despite how the pandas arrange the headers of the excels.

I am aware that using the code `df = df[[the order I want]]` can determine a header that I want but the set of data I am using is just a test to my actual cleaning project which have around 50 headers and I wish to have something more efficient than typing all 50 headers.

Can you show me the python code for it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is case 1 vs case 2? if pandas is returning different things for the same DataFrame in response to `df.sort_index(axis=1)` on two different systems then this is a great, simple question by itself - can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I am not sure if this is clear enough but I provided the two types of lists that I encountered on the two devices.

Comment: are you looking to swap the mixed up values in the `product` and `cost` columns round?  Like `df['product'],df['cost']=np.where(df['cost'].str.contains(r'\d{2}\.\d\d?', regex=True),(df['product'],df['cost']),(df['cost'],df['product']))
`

Comment: @MDR, thank you for the help. I see how this can fix the current issue, and this was one of my initial ideas. But for a more complex data frame with more columns, this is not going to be as much a efficient solution. Also, there can be other order of the array, like maybe cost and prime get switched or name and gender is mixed up. .0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the problem with differences across systems - check the basics like python/pandas version etc. (for example: `pip show pandas` in a terminal) and do check that the file being imported is exactly the same (even perhaps doing a checksum on it).

For swapping values in the wrong columns around maybe this helps...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"product":{"0":"comic","1":"14.00","2":"headphone","3":"20.23","4":"pen"},
                   "cost":{"0":"50.55","1":"paint","2":"45.00","3":"phone case","4":"66.00"},
                   "used_by":{"0":"female","1":"male","2":"female","3":"male","4":"female"},
                   "prime":{"0":"yes","1":"no","2":"no","3":"yes","4":"no"}})


print(df, '\n\n')

df['product'],df['cost']=np.where(df['cost']
                                  .str.contains(r'\d{2}\.\d\d?',
                                                regex=True),(df['product'],df['cost']),
                                  (df['cost'],df['product']))

df['cost'] = df['cost'].astype(float)

print(df)
```

**Output (before and after):**

```
     product        cost used_by   prime
0      comic       50.55  female   yes
1      14.00       paint    male    no
2  headphone       45.00  female    no
3      20.23  phone case    male   yes
4        pen       66.00  female    no 


      product   cost used_by   prime
0       comic  50.55  female   yes
1       paint  14.00    male    no
2   headphone  45.00  female    no
3  phone case  20.23    male   yes
4         pen  66.00  female    no
```

`df.info()` shows:

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   product  5 non-null      object 
 1   cost     5 non-null      float64
 2   used_by  5 non-null      object 
 3   prime    5 non-null      object
```

The regex of `\d{2}\.\d\d?` above is based on valid `costs` items being strings of `17.0` or perhaps `17.01`.  It may need updating depending on what you have in the data.